# Plane of all points equidistant from two other points?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

Find the equation of the plane that contains all the points that are equidistant from the given points

$(-9, 3, 3), (6, -2, 4)$

I think the plane described lies in the midpoint of these points, and it is perpendicular to the line connecting the two points. This means that the point $\left(\dfrac{15}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{7}{2}\right)$ is on the plane, and vector line perpendicular to the plane is $<-9-6, 3-(-2), 3-4>=<-15, 5, -1>$ . So the equation of the plane is $$-15(x-\dfrac{15}{2})+5(y-\dfrac12)-(z-\dfrac72)=0$$ or $$15x-5y+z-\dfrac{227}{2}=0$$ However, this seems to be the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your midpoint is incorrectly calculated. Other than that, the line is perpendicular to the plane, so you can get your dr's and coefficients of the plane equation from there as you have correctly done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The midpoint is $\left(\frac{-3}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{2} \right)$

Answer (score 2):

Notice, there is another easy method to find the equation of the plane

Let the parametric point be $(x, y)$ on the plane which is equidistant from the given points $(-9, 3, 3)$ & $(6, -2, 4)$ hence, we have $$\sqrt{(x-(-9))^2+(y-3)^2+(z-3)^2}=\sqrt{(x-6)^2+(y-(-2))^2+(z-4)^2}$$
$$(x+9)^2+(y-3)^2+(z-3)^2=(x-6)^2+(y+2)^2+(z-4)^2$$
$$((x+9)^2-(x-6)^2)+((y-3)^2-(y+2)^2)+((z-3)^2-(z-4)^2)=0$$
$$(x+9+x-6)(x+9-x+6)+(y-3+y+2)(y-3-y-2)+(z-3+z-4)(z-3-z+4)=0$$
$$15(2x+3)-5(2y-1)+(2z-7)=0$$
$$30x-10y+2z+43=0$$$$\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{\color{blue}{\text{Equation of the plane:}\ 30x-10y+2z+43=0}}$$